# Setting the "Thanks for following me" text seen by a new Twitter follower

Tags: twitter

I want to modify the default text that gets sent out to new Twitter followers.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know twitter has no option for sending an automatic DM to your new followers.
You are probably using a 3rd party service like [socialoomph](http://www.socialoomph.com/) (formerly TweetLater) that does this for you.
You should check out the settings on your web services which are connected to your twitter account.

Comment: it really is not a core feature of Twitter? Wow, I would've never figured that, guess if that is true, then I'll have to go one by one over the connected apps and see which one it is.... how inconvenient it all is!